# Firebase load data on page load instead of on click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm having a problem where Firebase only loads the data for my react page after a component has been clicked in the function. Here is my code for my container Header which maps 3 Widgets from the firebase firestore database and 3 hardcoaded cards which are identical to the widgets.

```
import './Header.css'
import HeaderCard from "./HeaderCard";
import React from "react";
import './sidebar.css'
import db from "./base";
import Widget from "./Widget";

let data = [];
db.collection("vyg_widgets")
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
   data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
});


function Header(){

    return(
        <div className="header">
            <div className="card_deck">
                
                {data.map((widget) => {
                    return(
                        <Widget info={widget.init_url}></Widget>
                    )
                })}
                <HeaderCard card_header={"Order Bookings"} card_info={"12"}></HeaderCard>

                <HeaderCard card_header={"Invoice Amt"} card_info={"₹72,92,400"}></HeaderCard>

                <HeaderCard card_header={"Previous Month Invoice Amt"} card_info={"₹13,94,268"}></HeaderCard>

                

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

Here is my code for the Widget

```
import React from "react";
import db from "./base";
import './HeaderCard.css'

function Widget(props){
    const [title, setTitle] = React.useState([]);
    const [total, setTotal] = React.useState([]);
    const [variance, setVariance] = React.useState([]);

    function getData(collection){
        let data = [];
        db.collection(collection)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
        data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        setTitle(data[0].title)
        setTotal(data[0].total)
        setVariance(data[0].variance * 100)
        });
    }
    return(
        <div className="card_container">
            {getData(props.info)}
            <h4 className="card_header">{title}</h4>
            <a href="#" className="card_info">{total}</a>
            <p className="percentage">{variance}%</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Widget;
```

And finally here is my code to HeaderCard which is identical to Widget without the firebase loading

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './HeaderCard.css'

function HeaderCard(props){
        return(
            <div className="card_container">
                <h4 className="card_header">{props.card_header}</h4>
                <a href="#" className="card_info">{props.card_info}</a>
                <p className="percentage">+4%</p>
            </div>
        )
}
```

The Widgets only show up when an action such as clicking on the HeaderCard is performed. I want it to to show up on page load. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to perform actions you want to happen when your components load. You can load data from Firebase and then set the components state with this data using the `useState` hook.

Here's how to do it:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import db from "./base";
import './Header.css'
import HeaderCard from "./HeaderCard";
import './sidebar.css'
import Widget from "./Widget";

const Header = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       db.collection("vyg_widgets")
       .get()
       .then(querySnapshot => {
        setData(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())); // data should now be set and ready to be used in your components
     });
    }, [])

     return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="card_deck">
            
            {data.map((widget) => {
                return(
                    <Widget info={widget.init_url}></Widget>
                )
            })}
            {/* include rest of your JSX here */}
            </div>
        </div>
     )
}

export default Header;
```

Here's a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-leftpad-51c3c?file=/src/App.js) with a mock api request to show the concept in action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I tried going about it this way, the data still doesn't seem to loaded and saved and thus React throws me an error saying "cannot map undefined". Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @HariKrishnaSenthilkumar Inside the `useEffect`, before the call to `setState`, try to `console.log` the value of your data and see if it's undefined there

Comment: I tried outputting the variable data before map is called and it seems to be loaded in. But when map is called, it says its undefined. This seems weird

Comment: Yes @itsanewabstract it seems to be undefined before setData is called.

Comment: I set the initial state to [] in the setState and this solved the problem. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @HariKrishnaSenthilkumar Yes, I just edited the code to fix this typo and included a working example to make sure the react code was working correctly even if there was a problem with the db. Glad to help!